# Из за чего ошибка выводится в виде строки?

Tags: php, xdebug

Подскажите пожалуйста, из за чего ошибка выводится в виде строки, а не как табличка?

Comment: дайте больше информации, где и что не так выводится

Comment: возможно изза того что кто-то её (ошибку) перехватывает.

Comment: В пхп поставил модуль xdebug, и при ошибочном коде выдает ошибку не в виде таблицы http://itforweb.com/upload/iblock/2b6/var_dump_full.jpg, а весь такой текст одной строкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очень просто из-за 
html_errors = Off

поставьте в On и будет вам счастье :)

сам намучался с этим..

Comment: давно уж разобрался, но спасибо =)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть неправильно поставил xdebug, или же установил какую-то "кастрированную" версию. Ну или на крайняк, посмотри, может быть там есть какие нибудь конфиги.